# Option to re-enable compiz missing in the appearance settings, how do I enable it?

Tags: 11.04, compiz

I have been upgrading my desktop for several version now and have been using metacity, the option to renable compiz is no longer in the appearance settings.

What is the best way to do this so it is persistent across restarts? (Save it to my gnome session)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose the type of session at the login screen "Gnome Classic" instead of "Gnome Classic (without effects).

After that you can install Compiz Settings Manager with Ubuntu Software Center to enable some effects. Be careful with some settings.

Comment: Seems like it should be the right answer but this one is using metacity as well. I probably broke this session at some point?

Comment: Have you tried to create a new user and login with these? Perhaps your config is corrupted...